# Get all nodes based on a specific parameter with JAC

Tags: jaseci

I want to return a list of nodes or a/all the variables within those node.
The list would look like this:
["node1" ,"node2", "node3"]

```
node_list --> node::node_type ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `node_list = --> node::node_type;`